# Opencv Array of strings?

Tags: c++, opencv, label

I want to classify images using SVM and i need to give it the labels, in Matlab i would do:

```
labels = {'ball';'plane';'person'};
```

how to make this in opencv? my following code failed:

```
Mat_<string> M (3,1);
M.at<string>(0) = "ball";
M.at<string>(1) = "plane"; 
M.at<string>(2) = "person";
```

Comment: no, that won't work. strings are not acceptable as content for cv::Mat. also the labels for the SVM have to be int (or float, if you want to do a regression, not a classification)

Comment: if you want 'named' labels, use a vector<string> on the side, and use the svm labels as index into that.